# Data Migration from one cloud another cloud

Tags: sql, mongodb

I am new in NoSql,I want to migrate SQL data into NoSQL from one cloud to another cloud using JSON file or is there any other way to perform migration ..please advice!

Comment: this a very broad question - what did you already researched?

Comment: I have applied denormalization on SQL tables and extracted data in JSON file.

Comment: I want JSON's data on different cloud storage (Mongodb).

Comment: did you tried import this json on local PC?

Comment: yes i can import JSON on mongodb which is on my local pc